# Laravel API and React js beginner here. I keep getting Error 422 in my application even though I am passing the required field

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-api

I have been trying to debug this error for a while now. I tried scouring the internet for solutions, yet I still can't find the fix for it. I am passing the required data for the API to work, but the error is still there.

**Laravel Controller**

```
protected function searchAdmin(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'admin_ref' => 'string|required'
    ]);

    $admin = adminInfos::where('adminID', $data['admin_ref'])->first();

    if (!$admin) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => '404',
            'message' => $this->response['AccntNtFnd']
        ]);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => '200',
            'account' => $admin
        ]);
    }
}
```

**React JS**

```
const searchAdmin = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/admin/adminSearch`, {
        'headers':{
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
        },
        'data':{
             'admin_ref': adminInput.searchInput
        }
    }).then(res=>{
        if(res.data.status != 200){
            console.log(res.data.message)
        }else{
            console.log(res.data.message)
        }
    }).catch(error => {
       console.log(error.response.data)
    });
  
}
```

UPDATE: I followed Nelson's advice, but the error still exists. Thank you for the advice tho, will make sure to take note of it.

Comment: I would stir away from using capitals in dbs, use underscores, changing engines would be easier. in your code up above you are asking for adminID in the lara side by then when you look at the code sent from the js side there is no adminID sent, only adminRef

Comment: alright, thanks for telling me. I have already revised my question

Comment: @Nelson, thanks for the help, but unfortunately the error is still there. I have also modified the code per your advice but sadly it did not fix the error

Comment: Thanks for updating; much better now. Did you double-check that `'admin_ref': adminInput.searchInput` is actually populated? If that was `undefined`, or `''`, then validation would fail.

Comment: @TimLewis, yes I double-checked if it was actually populated. I was able to see the value in the console using the console.log command

Comment: That's good, I figured as much. Does your code work if you remove the `$request->validate()` call? (You'd have to change to `$data = $request->input()` instead). Or, can you successfully call this code from with Laravel? I'm curious if you have a middleware or something else preventing this.

Comment: @TimLewis, it did work with $data=$request->input() and thanks for that, but the thing now is that even though I typed an existing id, it returns as not found. The newly modified line is now $data = $request->input('admin_ref').

Comment: Interesting; if you modify your code as `dd($request->input('admin_ref'))`, do you get `null` (or `''`)? Also, if you use `firstOrFail()` instead of `first()`, then it'll trigger a 404 instead of trying to input/reference a `null` variable.

Comment: I modified it using dd() and it gave me 
'.' as a response

Comment: $request->validate() would just validate your inputs in case you need to force the user to give it to you every time. $request->input('admin_ref') or $reques->all()  will give you the actual values (input just one parameter sent and all... all the parameters) I would try the dd() on $request->all() just to check what you are sending on the get request. also, would you mind showing the html just for that input you are pulling the data from and a idea of what rows are in the db table where you are pulling the data from. Just to make sure you arent missing anything there as well.